# How to pivot horizontal data into vertical data and assign values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table TR_1 with 5 columns that all contain text fields.

The structure of the column headers  is below:

```
Manager  |Customer|Customer-Role|Status |Urgency
John     |X       |Contractor   |Active-|Low
Paul     |Y       |Painter      |Active |High
```

I want to assign an account value to each of these columns so that the result is the below for example account S01 represents Manager and Account S02 represents Customer:

```
Account | Text
S01     | John
S01     | Paul
S02     |   X
S02     |   Y
```

Is there any possible way to do this..i dont have an account table and just want to assign fixed values to each of the five columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select v.*
from t outer apply
     (values ('S01', Manager),
             ('S02', Customer)
     ) v(account, text);
```